# Setting SQL Date field value based off Week Number and Day Number Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-arithmetic

Is there a procedure or means of setting the Date value based off a week value and day value.

To elaborate further using this calendar year:
January 1st-7th is week 1, 
January 8th-14th is week 2 etc.

As for Day number value; 
Monday is 1
Tuesday is 2
Wednesday is 3
Thursday is 4
Friday is 5.

Using this logic I wish to create and populate a date field that uses these values.

For instance, I want Week: 2 - Day: 3 to populate my new date field as  10/1/2018

Any help and guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Some things can be done with the datetime functions to calculate a date from just the week number and the weekday number.

However, beware that `@@DATEFIRST` can be different on a server.
Which defines which weekday is the first day in the week.
So it's best change it in your session to 1 to make Monday the first weekday.
Without it there might be an adjustment needed in the calculation used below.
For example `[Weekday]+1` when `select @@DATEFIRST` returns 7

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @Table table ([Week] int, [Weekday] int);

insert into @Table ([Week], [Weekday]) values
 (1, 1)
,(1, 7)
,(2, 1)
,(2, 7)
;

-- The US default for @@DATEFIRST is 7, which would make Sunday weekday 1. 
-- By setting @@DATEFIRST to 1 then Monday will be weekday 1
SET DATEFIRST 1; 

SELECT [Week], [Weekday],
DATEADD(WEEKDAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,GetDate()),1,1)), DATEADD(WEEK,[Week]-1, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,GetDate()),1,[Weekday]))) AS CalcDate
FROM @Table
ORDER BY [Week], [Weekday];
```

**Result:**

```
Week Weekday CalcDate
---- ------- ----------
   1       1 2018-01-01
   1       7 2018-01-07
   2       1 2018-01-08
   2       7 2018-01-14
```

Note that the year is based on the current date.

But if it's to update an existing table?
Then you could look at it in another way.
Create a temp table with all the dates in the current year, and derive the week & weekday from those dates.
Then you can use that temp table to update your existing table.

**Example snippet:**

```
-- Create a temporary table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpDates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpDates;
CREATE TABLE #tmpDates ([Week] INT NOT NULL, [WeekDay] INT NOT NULL, [Date] DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ([Week], [WeekDay]));

-- Make Monday the first weekday
SET DATEFIRST 1;

-- Filling the temp table with data
WITH DATES2018 AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AS [Date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, [Date])
  FROM DATES2018
  WHERE [Date] < CAST('2018-12-31' AS DATE)
)
INSERT INTO #tmpDates ([Date], [Week], [WeekDay])
SELECT [Date], DATEPART(WEEK, [Date]) AS [Week], DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]) as [WeekDay]
FROM DATES2018
ORDER BY [Week], [WeekDay]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366);


-- Just using a table variable per demonstration
declare @YourTable table ([Week] int, [Weekday] int, [Date] DATE);
-- Sample data
insert into @YourTable ([Week], [Weekday]) values
 (1, 1)
,(1, 7)
,(2, 1)
,(2, 7)
;

-- update based on the temp table
update t
set [Date] = tmp.[Date]
from @YourTable t 
join #tmpDates tmp on (tmp.[Week] = t.[Week] AND tmp.[WeekDay] = t.[Weekday])
where (t.[Date] is null OR t.[Date] <> tmp.[Date]);

select * from @YourTable;
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you. What I'm finding difficult to understand is how I would use this to update another table that has a blank CalcDate field using a weekno and dayno field that is in the same row.

Comment: @potatochucker Just look for how to normally update a table, and use the calculation. As in: `update yourtable set yourfield = <put calculation here> where yourfield is null`. But if it's for a 1-time update I would hardcode the year instead of calculating it from GetDate.

Comment: @potatochucker I tweaked the calculation a bit.

Comment: Thanks for all your insight and help. I've implemented your code and tested it on my end but I have an issue where I need this to go beyond the scope of a single year. I have a field that records the Year value '2018', '2019' etc. Coluld this be used as a means of setting an overall date without have to declare each given year and inserting it into tmpDates? Or is there a way of inserting multiple years into the tmp dates? Thanks again!

Comment: @potatochucker You should have a closer look at the second solution in the table.  You could set variables for the startDate and endDate, then just use those in the SQL for #tmpDates. And rename the `DATE2018` CTE to just `DATES`. (because it sounds wrong for dates from 2017 ;p) And set the MAXRECURSION higher or to 0. Actually, instead of #temporary table, it could be made as a permanent table with extra date related fields.  To make it reusable for other queries, typically named `Calendar`.

Comment: Everything is working perfect now. I made a calendar table like you suggest and for now i set a span between 2018-2022. I then used this to update the table and all calculated dates using the Week Number and Day No are filled out. You have been really helpful. Have a wonderful week/life

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link which has a calendar table creation statement
https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/

What you need to do is map your available columns like year, week and day to the calendar table and extract the date

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this can get you started.
It will return the date from your sample, but I did not tested in all situations...
So I am sure it will need some finetuning and using a `Calender Table` as @Ajan-Balakumaran suggests would be far better

```
declare @year int = datepart(year, getdate())
declare @month int
declare @week int = 2
declare @day int = 3

SELECT @month = DATEPART(MM,CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(3),
                         DATEADD(WW, @WEEK - 1,
                         CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/' + CONVERT(char(4) ,@Year)))
                         , 100) + ' 1900' AS DATETIME))

select datefromparts(2018, @month, @day + (@week - 1) * 7)
```